# Trouble embedding clang in a standalone application

Tags: make, c++

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on my end and I have **installed clang** as well as **libclang-dev** and **llvm** (through apt). I tried hard to run **RecursiveASTVisitor** example given here:-

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html

but no luck. One thing also annoying me is:

```
Unknown CMake command "llvm_map_components_to_libraries"
```

I don't know how to write a CMakeLists.txt file, but here is what I am using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
  "."
)

find_package(LibClang REQUIRED)

find_package(LLVM)

if(NOT LLVM_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Fatal Error: LLVM cannot be found.")
endif()

add_definitions(${LibClang_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(
  ${LibClang_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories( ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

add_executable(ast TestCLang.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ast
  ${LibClang_LIBRARIES}
)

include_directories( ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

llvm_map_components_to_libraries(REQ_LLVM_LIBRARIES jit native)

#target_link_libraries(ast REQ_LLVM_LIBRARIES)

#add_subdirectory(test)

set(LLVM_USED_LIBS clangTooling)

#add_clang_executable(find-class-decls TestCLang.cpp)
```

I cannot use **llvm_map_components_to_libraries** or **add_clang_executable** as it complains about not knowing these commands. I guess I am using LLVM-3.2.
Here is my **FindLibClang.cmake**:

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND llvm-config --cxxflags
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE LibClang_DEFINITIONS)

set(LibClang_DEFINITIONS ${LibClang_DEFINITIONS} "-fno-rtti")

execute_process(
  COMMAND llvm-config --includedir
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE LibClang_INCLUDE_DIR)

find_library(LibClang_LIBRARY NAMES clang)

set(LibClang_LIBRARIES ${LibClang_LIBRARY})
set(LibClang_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LibClang_INCLUDE_DIR})

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(LibClang DEFAULT_MSG LibClang_LIBRARY LibClang_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(LibClang_INCLUDE_DIR LibClang_LIBRARY)
```

May be wrong on my end?

Comment: Take a look at your cmakeslist file. The function being complained about is commented out.

Comment: Oh yes because I needed to do something to avoid the error.

Comment: You should edit your post then to show the file as it is when it produces the error you are asking about.